# Unable to use proguard with kotlin and Java classes

Tags: android, kotlin, android-proguard, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm unable to generate signed apk using `proguard`. I am facing the below error.

> Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Can't write [/Users/xyztech-Android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/proguard/prod/release/0.jar] (Can't read [/Users/xyztech-Android/app/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/prodRelease(;;;;;;**.class)] (Can't read [com] (Can't read [xyztech] (Can't read [xyztech] (Can't read [models] (Can't read [Sender.class] (Duplicate zip entry [com/xyztech/models/Sender.class])))))))

I have used the blow commands in my `proguard` file

```
-keep class com.xyztech.models.** { *; }

-dontwarn kotlin.**
```

Answer (score 0):

In all the can't write issues it is sane to first check if it's not folder permissions issue(especially if you developing on Linux). Might not have anything to do with Proguard precisely.